# Truncate schema in HSQLDB

Tags: hibernate, hsqldb

I'm using HSQLDB for my unit tests. The problem is that my project contains really many tests and dropping the whole DB and recreating it for each and every test takes a really significant amount of time. I found that new HSQLDB contains the possibility of removing data from schema without really dropping the tables, what is significantly more efficient. The only problem is that I have two schemas and tables that relate to one another. So normally I would write

```
getSession().createSQLQuery("TRUNCATE SCHEMA aaa AND COMMIT").executeUpdate();
getSession().createSQLQuery("TRUNCATE SCHEMA bbb AND COMMIT").executeUpdate();
```

(where aaa and bbb would be the names of my schemas)
The problem is that aaa contains tables that reference tables in bbb and bbb contains tables that reference tables in aaa, hence there are always some foreign keys that prevent me from executing those commands one after another.
How could I possibly run it, so that all data from my DB gets purged?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with an option:

```
TRUNCATE SCHEMA aaa AND COMMIT NO CHECK
```